# Can web.config have a general system.webserver section and other system.webserver sections with location tags?

Tags: iis-7.5

I want to place url rewrites in a global system.webserver section for all my sites - but I'd like requestFiltering sections for particular sites - can I have a "main" system.webserver section and then a bunch of others within location sections?

Comment: You probably misunderstood how IIS works, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis If you want something "global for all sites", then it must be in `applicationHost.config`, not any `web.config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have a "global" system.webServer section (group) and many "location specific" configuration sections which have their own system.webServer section (group).  You can have this in both the ApplicationHost.config and inside each and every web.config.  The one problem with your question though is asking for a general system.webServer section in a web.config to apply to all sites.   Unless all sites share the same physical path, you won't be able to use a single web.config for all sites.  Instead, you'd want to place this configuration in the ApplicationHost.config.  Some light reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/getting-started-with-configuration-in-iis-7-and-above